# Could the implicit destructor of a polymorphic class be made virtual?

Tags: c++, destructor, virtual-destructor

As far as I'm aware, it is always a mistake (or at the very least, asking for trouble) to define a class with virtual functions but a non-virtual destructor.

As such (and thinking about the newly-coined "rule of zero"), it seems to me that the implicitly generated destructor should automatically be virtual for any class with at least one other virtual function.

Would it be feasible for some future version of the C++ standard to mandate this? Or to put it another way, are there any good reasons to keep the default destructor non-virtual in a polymorphic class?

**EDIT:** Just to make it clear, I'm only suggesting what might happen if you *don't* write a destructor -- if you do write your own, you of course get to choose whether it's virtual or not, as ever. I'd just like to see the default match the common case (without preventing more advanced usage).

Comment: You don't always delete objects from a pointer to the base class. In fact, you don't always allocate them dynamically, even if you do use them polymorphically.

Comment: There is no implicitly generated destructor for a class that has virtual functions.

Comment: @juanchopanza Of course not. But if you have a single virtual function, you're paying for the vtable anyway: what extra cost is there for a virtual destructor too? Virtual function overhead is negligible next to the cost of `delete`, I would have thought

Comment: Both defining and calling a virtual destructor have a run-time cost. A general principle of C++ is not to impose run-time costs when they're not needed; and polymorphic deletion is not always needed.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Yes there is. All classes get an implicit destructor if you don't declare an explicit one.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I meant to state that as a question, sorry.

Comment: 99% of the time you are correct. But I doubt it will ever go into the standard because it would significantly change too much existing (admittedly perhaps bad) code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want or need to polymorphically delete such objects it's not needed that the destructor be virtual. Instead it can be `protected` non-virtual in the base class, allowing only to be deleted non-polymorphically. Requiring it to be automatically virtual would then impose an undue cost on applications that don't need polymorphic destruction.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that the destructor must always be virtual, but only what happens if you don't supply one. If you write your own (as you'd have to to make it `protected`) you get to choose whether its virtual or not, as ever. I'd just like to see the default match the common case (without preventing more advanced usage).